# Global Variable in HTML Body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to HTML. I am trying to create a static HTML site with multiple pages linked to one-another like in a sequence of pages. I am using a free bootstrap template for this. Most of the pages have dates across multiple tables. I already created most of the pages with their dates. The dates are unique within a page but same across all pages. The dates may require frequent changes. It would be difficult to make those changes for each page individually. I want to know if I can use variables that I can declare in a Javascript file and show the value from those variables in the HTML body in the respective tables. Any samples

I tried to check online using keywords like Global variable in HTML, etc. but couldn't find anything specific to my scenario. I was told that it is possible using Javascript. Maybe my approach of using global variables is wrong or maybe there is a simpler way to this. Would be grateful for any help in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create a simple map. Map each date to a page name. `var myMap = {'page1.html': 'Date For Page1'};
alert(myMap['page1.html']);`

Comment: Show us what you tried so far.

Comment: @HanletEscaño: I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: @SamparaVignan You might need an array btw.

Comment: @Ravimallya: I have not tried anything because I didn't find anything similar to my scenario. However, I found http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/a9cvx/4/ right after I posted this question. Will try this and give an update

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP Includes](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp), pretty simple to use.

Create a new file and save it as .php. Ex: **globalvars.php**

```
<?php
 <script>
    var global_x = 10;
 </script>
?>
```

Then add this line into the first line of your pages, and **save it as .php file** to read globalvars.php.

```
<?php include "globalvars.php"; ?>
<!<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 ...
```

The browser will read your script like this... It simply copies the content of globalvars.php and inserting it on the place of `<?php include "globalvars.php"; ?>`

```
<script>
 var global_x = 10;
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be working at all. Its localStorage (JS is very case sensitive), and to save an item, you use setItem, change your syntax to:

```
localStorage.setItem('variableName', value);
```

for get you can use..

```
localStorage.getItem('variableName');
```

Comment: Thanks for the lead. I tried this and it worked. localStorage.setItem("variableName", "Friday 11-26-2016 09:52:42");

document.getElementById("firstdate").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("variableName");

Comment: But when I try to use multiple entries of local storage for multiple dates, nothing is displayed. What can I do to have multiple dates at different locations in the HTML body?